# Sublime Regular Expression

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

I have this

```
(?i)^\s*(function|procedure|package)\s+([-a-z0-9_]+)
```

Which can find whenever I write something like `function foo` or `procedure foo`.

How can I change that to be able to catch this way ?

`function
         foo`

I tried adding this `\n` before the `\s+` but no success.

I have this way:

```
<dict>
<key>captures</key>
<dict>
    <key>1</key>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>storage.type.function.oracle</string>
    </dict>
    <key>2</key>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>entity.name.function.oracle</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>match</key>
<string>(?i)(function|procedure|package)\s+([-a-z0-9_]+)</string>
<key>name</key>
<string>meta.function.oracle</string>
```

Comment: No, it should've been `[\n\s]+`. Still makes little sense, as `\n` is in `\s` charclass. Are you sure the regex isn't applied line by line?

Comment: I don't really know, I'm editing a Oracle syntax already made and adapting it for my needs. I dont know anything about sublime syntax only concluded that it could possibly work with regular expressions.

Comment: @SnakeSheet you mean this http://regex101.com/r/jZ2bH6/9 ?

Comment: With works with different online regex but it doesn't assume in sublime :(

Comment: maybe you can simply replace new lines with space before matching regex with it?

Answer (score 0):

The below regex works for me,

```
(?i)(function|procedure|package)\s+([-a-z0-9_]+)
```

[image]